# Connect Power Bi to Postgres on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: postgresql, powerbi

I am trying to connect my Power BI to my Database postgres on GCP.
I was able to connect it with Tableau and Datagrip but I'm struggling with PBI.

I followed [this guide](https://www.tradefinanceglobal.com/posts/connecting-powerbi-web-to-postgressql-hosted-on-aws-relational-database-service-rds/) but the difference is on paragraph 2 because I don't need a AWS public key but a GCP and here is my problem.

I tried to create a public key with these command

```
$openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out rsa_private.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
$openssl rsa -in rsa_private.pem -pubout -out rsa_public.pem
writing RSA key
```

and then I tried to create the certificate using [the link](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html) in the guide and then applying the certificate using MMC.
I got the error message that the certificate was empty so I think I didn't create it right.

I never did something like this before so I really don't have any clue.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I should do instead?

Thank you

Comment: How'd you set up the Cloud SQL instance? SSL-only connections allowed? Is that why you're trying to create the certs? Did you set up the Connectivity as Public IP or Private IP? And if Public IP, did you authorize the network where you're trying to connect from? There's a lot of variables here that's subtly different than RDS, so following their guide to connect to Cloud SQL isn't going to work 1:1. I wrote a series of blog posts about connectivity that might help, start here: https://medium.com/google-cloud/connecting-google-cloud-sql-94025ba27071

Comment: I am also interested in this question. I already have a GC-SQL instance, working and I am able to access it using PGAdmin from my local machine.